# How to generate embeddings of object images detected with YOLOv5?

Tags: python, yolo, embedding

I want to run real time object detection using YOLOv5 on a camera and then generate vector embeddings for cropped images of detected objects.

I currently generate image embeddings using this function below for locally saved images:

```py
def generate_img_embedding(img_file_path):
    images = [
        Image.open(img_file_path)
    ]
    # Encoding a single image takes ~20 ms
    embeddings = embedding_model.encode(img_str)

    return embeddings
```

also I start the Yolov5 objection detection with image cropping as follows

```py
def start_camera(productid):
    print("Attempting to start camera")
    # productid = "11011"

    try:
        command = " python ./yolov5/detect.py  --source 0 --save-crop --name "+ id +" --project ./cropped_images"
        os.system(command)
        print("Camera runnning")
    except Exception as e:
        print("error starting camera!", e)
```

How can I modify the YOLOv5 model to pass the cropped images into my embedding function in real time?

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at the `detect.py` supplied with yolov5, the file you are running. The implementation is pretty short (~150 SLOC), I would recommend re-implementing it or modifying for your use case.

Key points, omitting a lot of (important, but standard and easily understandable) data transforms and parameter parsing, are as follows:

```
device = select_device(device)
model = DetectMultiBackend(weights, device=device, dnn=dnn, data=data)
# Code selecting FP16/FP32 omitted here
model.warmup(imgsz=(1 if pt else bs, 3, *imgsz), half=half)
for path, im, im0s, vid_cap, s in dataset:
    im = torch.from_numpy(im).to(device)
    # Image transforms omitted
    pred = model(im, augment=augment, visualize=visualize)  # stage 1
    pred = non_max_suppression(pred, conf_thres, iou_thres, classes, agnostic_nms, max_det=max_det)  # stage 2

    for i, det in enumerate(pred):
        if len(det):
            # Rescale boxes from img_size to im0 size
            det[:, :4] = scale_coords(im.shape[2:], det[:, :4], im0.shape).round()

            # --> This is where you would access detections in real time! <--
```

Most of the code's logic is handling the I/O (in particular, dataset loading is handled by either `LoadStreams` or `LoadImages` from yolov5's `utils`), the rest is just rescaling input images, loading a torch model, and running detection and NMS. No rocket science here.

The least effort path for you would be just copying the entire thing and implementing your embeddings under

```
for *xyxy, conf, cls in reversed(det):
```

Instead of saving to file, you would get (x, y, w, h) and crop the image using e.g. Pillow's `Image.crop()` or slice the numpy array directly. Whichever works for you depends on the implementation of your `embedding_model.encode`.